# Azure search window function

Tags: elasticsearch, azure-cognitive-search

If I have a history of documents in my index, is it possible to retrieve all the latest ones?
So let's say I have product records, and the product with a productid property of "myprod" appears 5 times with slightly different data, each one time-stamped.
And when I do a search with a date, I want all the product records valid at that date, ie where the date is less than search date and is the max for that product.
Easy in SQL. Possible in Azure search? Or even elastic search if we have to move?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You sure can add a range filter for this purpose in both elastic search and azure search.

I assume that your data is formatted as a date and in elastic search all you have to do is

```
    "filter": {
      "range": {
        "<the date field name>": {
          "gte": "2018-01-01",
          "lte": "2018-01-01"
        }
      }
    }
```

and in azure search

```
filter=<the date field name> ge 2018-01-01T00:00:00-08:00  and <the date field name> le 2018-01-01T00:00:00-08:00
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to filter records as you described you would need do 3 things:

1. $filter by date (like [gd vigneshwar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8035076/gd-vigneshwar) already suggested)
2. $orderby date
3. Pick only distinct productids that occur first on the sorted list

Unfortunately 3. has to happen on client/server side.

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately neither of these is a solution. The date criteria is not relevant. It is the latest per product. That could be yesterday or it could be 5 years ago. Then doing 3 in a separate function would be awful for performance and remove all the pagination advantages. Though I suppose technically it is a solution, it's not one that uses the search engine exclusively which was the idea. But thanks for the ideas

Comment: When I say date criteria is not relevant I of course mean the gte one, which in the example seems pointless anyway as it is the same one as lte which basically means eq